# Is substitution failure an error with dependent non-type template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, template-aliases

Let's say I have these template aliases:

```
enum class enabler {};

template <typename T>
using EnableIf = typename std::enable_if<T::value, enabler>::type;
template <typename T>
using DisableIf = typename std::enable_if<!T::value, enabler>::type;
```

I can do the following in GCC:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, EnableIf<std::is_polymorphic<T>> = {}>
void f(T) { std::cout << "is polymorphic\n"; }

template <typename T, DisableIf<std::is_polymorphic<T>> = {}>
void f(T) { std::cout << "is not polymorphic\n"; }

struct foo { virtual void g() {} };

int main() {
    f(foo {});
    f(int {});
}
```

It prints:

> is polymorphic
>   is not polymorphic

Which matches my expectations.

With clang that code does not compile. It produces the following error messages.

```
test.cpp:11:58: error: expected expression
template <typename T, EnableIf<std::is_polymorphic<T>> = {}>
                                                         ^
test.cpp:14:59: error: expected expression
template <typename T, DisableIf<std::is_polymorphic<T>> = {}>
                                                          ^
test.cpp:20:3: error: no matching function for call to 'f'
  f(foo {});
  ^
test.cpp:12:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument ''
void f(T) { std::cout << "is polymorphic\n"; }
     ^
test.cpp:15:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument ''
void f(T) { std::cout << "is not polymorphic\n"; }
     ^
test.cpp:21:3: error: no matching function for call to 'f'
  f(int {});
  ^
test.cpp:12:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument ''
void f(T) { std::cout << "is polymorphic\n"; }
     ^
test.cpp:15:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument ''
void f(T) { std::cout << "is not polymorphic\n"; }
     ^
4 errors generated.
```

Should it compile? Which of the two compilers is faulty?

Comment: Ooops, I feel silly. I have a feeling this has nothing to do with template aliases, so the title is possibly misleading :S Sorry about that, I'll investigate a bit and fix the title if that turns out the case.

Comment: `DisableIf<std::is_polymorphic<T>> = {}` is that legal initializer list initialization? Can structures be template value parameters?

Comment: @jpalecek No, structures can't. That's why I use an enum :)

Comment: Clang issues similar error messages if I don't use the aliases and just manually "inline" them, so I fixed the title.

Comment: Quickly scanning the standard, it seems to be legal, so it's probably an issue with clang. Does it still fail on clang if you change `enabler` to `int` and `{}` to `0`?

Comment: BTW, the standard says you should have at least one value in your enum.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to pass an enum as the second argument to the template? Why not `template <typename T, typename U = std::enable_if<std::is_polymorphic<T>>::type > void f( T );` ?

Comment: @jpalecek No, it doesn't say that. Check the grammar at §7.2, paragraph 1: the enumerator list is optional. Check also paragraph 6 for an explicit mention of an empty enumerator list.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas try it out on this code and you'll see. You'll end up redeclaring the *same* template with different default arguments, which is not allowed. More info on the thought process that led to this style of enable_if: http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/tips-and-tricks:enable-if-for-c-11

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Oh yes, it does. Read 7.2 par. 2: The optional identifier shall not be omitted in declaration of a scoped enumeration.

Comment: @jpalecek That's for the enum's *name*. It refers to the fact that `enum {}` is valid, but `enum class {}` isn't. Not at all relevant here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup>First and foremost, thanks to @[Richard Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1041090/richard-smith) on the [#llvm IRC Channel on oftc](http://llvm.org/docs/#irc) for the explanation.</sup>
Unfortunately, this is not legal C++ and as such Clang is correct: `{}` is not an expression but a *braced-init-list* and as such will never be a *constant* expression as is needed in the initializer of a non-type template parameter.

`§14.3.2 [temp.arg.non-type] p1`

> A *template-argument* for a non-type, non-template *template-parameter* shall be one of:
>
> - for a non-type *template-parameter* of integral or enumeration type, a converted **constant expression** (5.19) of the type of the *template-parameter*; or
> - [...]

One solution would be a dummy value in `enabler`.

Comment: That is not a good argument - we are not talking about template arguments here (noone tries eg. `f<int,{}>`), but default arguments, which have a syntax of a parameter-declaration, which can, in principle, have `{}` on the rhs (and if `enabler{}` is a constant expression, or `x`, given `enabler x{}`, there shouldn't be a problem with constant). However, 8.3.6/3 says there should be an expression in case of template parameter declaration.

Comment: @jpalecek: "oone tries eg. `f<int,{}>`" Uh, calling `f<int>` does *exactly* that.

Comment: @GManNickG: No, it doesn't. Default parameters are not specified (at least explicitly) as text substitutions.

Comment: @jpalecek: In what way does a default argument differ from a formal argument? In any case you can't just use `{}` because it can never be a constant expression, which is what's needed to initialize a non-type parameter.

Comment: @jpalecek Is paragraph 9 of 14.1 Template Parameters "A *default template-argument* is a *template-argument* (14.3) specified after `=` in a *template-parameter*." the missing argument in this case?