# C++: why this simple Scope Guard works?

Tags: c++, exception-safety, scopeguard

Every looked at scope guard so far has a guard boolean variable. For example, see this discussion:
[The simplest and neatest c++11 ScopeGuard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270328/the-simplest-and-neatest-c11-scopeguard)

But a simple guard works (gcc 4.9, clang 3.6.0):

```
template <class C>
struct finally_t : public C {
    finally_t(C&& c): C(c) {}
    ~finally_t() { (*this)(); }
};
template <class C>
static finally_t<C> finally_create(C&& c) {
    return std::forward<C>(c);
}
#define FINCAT_(a, b) a ## b
#define FINCAT(a, b) FINCAT_(a, b)
#define FINALLY(...) auto FINCAT(FINALY_, __LINE__) = \
    finally_create([=](){ __VA_ARGS__ })

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    FINALLY( std::cout << "hello" << a << std::endl ; );
    FINALLY( std::cout << "world" << a << std::endl ; );
    return 0;
}
```

Why no temporary copies destructed? Is it dangerous to rely on this behavior?

Comment: You're observing the effects of Copy Elision (or Move Elision, in this case). Copy Elision is **not** guaranteed / mandatory, but usually performed by major compilers even when compiling w/o optimizations. Try gcc's `-fno-elide-constructors` to see it "break": http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/B73EuYYKGYFMnJtR

Comment: There is a trick to not rely on copy elision, few changes are required. Here is [modification](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98effe1794da5c05) of your version which does not rely on copy elision.

Answer (score 1):

You're observing the effects of Copy Elision (or Move Elision, in this case). Copy Elision is not guaranteed / mandatory, but usually performed by major compilers even when compiling w/o optimizations. Try gcc's -fno-elide-constructors to see it "break": http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/B73EuYYKGYFMnJtR