# C++ : other one simple scope guard

Tags: c++, exception-safety, scopeguard

Lets ask you about this simple scope guard:

```
template <class T>
struct finop_t {
    T& t;
    ~finop_t() { t(); }
};
#define FINALLY__(l, cl) \
    auto FIN ## l ## clo = cl; \
    finop_t<decltype(FIN ## l ## clo)> FIN ## l ## fin { FIN ## l ## clo}
#define FINALLY_(l, cl) FINALLY__(l, cl)
#define FINALLY(...) FINALLY_(__LINE__, ([=](){__VA_ARGS__}))

int main() {
    FINALLY( std::cout << "hello" << std::endl ; );
    std::cout << "one" << std::endl;
    FINALLY( std::cout << "world" << std::endl ; );
    std::cout << "second" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is it safe to rely on destruction order here? i.e. is it safe assume that `~finop_t()` will be called before lambda destructor?

Comment: does this compile? You're assigning a temporary to a mutable l-value reference.

Comment: It does compile.
First, i initialize variable `FIN##l##clo` with a value of closure. (perhaps, copy elision helps here a bit).
Then a assign reference to `FIN##l##clo` to field `t` of variable `FIN##l##fin`.

Comment: ah i see. in that case why not store the object and initialise it directly? Copy elision will ensure no redundant copies and you'll have no indirection through a reference

Comment: if you tell me how to do it, I will be very glad. I haven't found simpler way to fight template argument deduction.

Comment: Well, i've made simple version which rely on copy elision http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922693/c-why-this-simple-scope-guard-works

Comment: answer posted as per your request.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is safe. The macro stores a lambda in a local variable. The destruction order for local variables is fixed (in the reverse order of construction). Thus it is guaranteed that `~finop_t()` destructor is called before the corresponding lambda (`FIN ## l ## clo`) destructor.

Answer (score 2):

Destruction of local variables takes place in the inverse order of their construction.

And here's a more efficient way, which needs no references and uses copy-elision to construct the lambda in-place.

(note, you may want to consider [&] rather than [=], but that's for you to judge)

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct finop_t {
    finop_t(T&& t) : t(std::forward<T>(t)) {}
    T t;
    ~finop_t() { t(); }
};

template<class F>
finop_t<F> make_finop_t(F&& f)
{
    return finop_t<F>(std::forward<F>(f));
}

#define FINALLY__(l, cl) \
auto FIN ## l ## fin = make_finop_t(cl);

#define FINALLY_(l, cl) FINALLY__(l, cl)
#define FINALLY(...) FINALLY_(__LINE__, ([=](){__VA_ARGS__}))

int main() {
    FINALLY( std::cout << "hello" << std::endl ; );
    std::cout << "one" << std::endl;
    FINALLY( std::cout << "world" << std::endl ; );
    std::cout << "second" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is almost the same as my version http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922693/c-why-this-simple-scope-guard-works
But I think it is not good thing to rely on copy elision within destructor (but may be, it is).

Comment: Oh, thank you for pointing to `[&]` !!! it is really makes a sense.

Comment: There is no copy elision during a destructor. It takes place during the call to `make_finop_t()` and as RVO (return value optimisation) when returned from `make_finop_t()` - c++11 gives us perfect forwarding all the way.

Comment: It's a bad idea to rely on copy elision of finop_t. It is not guaranteed.

Comment: @funny_falcon no problem. I like the sneaky technique to make unique variable names.

Comment: @avsmal well, the entire c++ standard library pretty much depends on it. While it's not 'guaranteed', compiler publishers are 'strongly advised' to implement it, which means realistically that no-one is going to use a compiler that does not do CE. Even if the compiler chose not to elide the copy, the code will still work - it would simply be discarding a copied-from function pointer. Still more efficient that calling through a reference.

Comment: >> There is no copy elision during a destructor.
<< But we rely on copy elision in a way that destructor should be called once. Every other ScopeGuard implementation make explicit boolean guard-flag which is cleared on copy, so that they are not rely on copy elision.

Comment: @funny_falcon but the guard object is never copied.

Comment: it is copied if `-fno-elide-constructors` flag passed to compiller (as @dyp shows in http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/B73EuYYKGYFMnJtR )

Comment: ah i see. fair enough - i guess put a flag in there and test it (then provide a move constructor). That will all get optimised away anyway.

Comment: That is what every one do :)

Comment: probably because in reality it results in the most efficient code :)

Comment: @RichardHodges  "the entire c++ standard library pretty much depends on it" - the entire C++ standard library still works correctly in the absence of copy elision. It may be less efficient but still correct.