# Is there a C++ standard class to set a variable to a value at scope exit

Tags: c++, return, raii, exception-safety

Within the scope of a member function, I want to temporarly set a member variable to a certain value.

Then, when this function returns, I want to reset this member variable to a given known value.

To bo safe against exceptions and multiple returns, and I've done it with a simple RAII like class. It's defined within the scope of the member function.

```
void MyClass::MyMemberFunction() {
    struct SetBackToFalse {
        SetBackToFalse(bool* p): m_p(p) {}
        ~SetBackToFalse() {*m_p=false;}
    private:
        bool* m_p;
    };

    m_theVariableToChange = true;
    SetBackToFalse resetFalse( &m_theVariableToChange ); // Will reset the variable to false.

    // Function body that may throw.
}
```

It seems so obviously commonplace, that I was wondering if there was any such template class doing this in the C++ standard library?

Comment: Interesting idea. Something I wonder: is there a reason to use a pointer vs a reference here?

Comment: I think there is no such thing in the standard library. Andrei Alexandrescu once built some generalization of the above with "lengthy" macro hacks.

Comment: @underscore_d No. You can implement it with a reference.

Comment: Also there is [Boost.ScopeExit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: _"It seems so obviously commonplace"_ It seems more obviously commonplace _not_ to do something so confusing and weird. Why don't you use a different variable instead?

Comment: @BaummitAugen: The concept of [ScopeGuards](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/generic-change-the-way-you-write-excepti/184403758) was really invented by Petru Marginean, rather than Andrei Alexandresu. Couldn't find an authoritative reference, so I'll have to take [Herb Sutter's word for it](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/).

Comment: @IInspectable I don't know who invented it, it's just the only implementation I know. But thx for the links. Also, from the [standards proposas](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4189.pdf): *"This proposal incorporates what Andrej Alexandrescu described as scope guard
long ago and explained again at C++ Now 2012 ()."* Iirc that's the talk I'm referring to above.

Comment: This construct will be absolutely deadly if the object is accessed from multiple threads.

Comment: @PeteBecker Equally deadly as `var = false;` ...

Comment: @M.M - not quite, since the code that resets the variable would be more-or-less invisible.

Comment: There is a proposal to introduce such a scope_guard feature in the standard by Peter Sommerlad: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3949.pdf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not yet (there have been proposals for this). But implementing a generic one is simple enough;

```
struct scope_exit {
  std::function<void()> f_;
  explicit scope_exit(std::function<void()> f) noexcept : f_(std::move(f)) {}
  ~scope_exit() { if (f_) f_(); }
};
// ...
m_theVariableToChange = true;
scope_exit resetFalse([&m_theVariableToChange]() { m_theVariableToChange = false; });
```

*For simplicity above, I've redacted the copy and move constructors etc...*

Marking them as `= delete` will make the above a minimal solution. Further; moving could be allowed if desired, but copying should be prohibited.

---

A more complete `scope_exit` would look like ([online demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5f75588e2fcba91));

```
template <typename F>
struct scope_exit {
  F f_;
  bool run_;
  explicit scope_exit(F f) noexcept : f_(std::move(f)), run_(true) {}
  scope_exit(scope_exit&& rhs) noexcept : f_((rhs.run_ = false, std::move(rhs.f_))), run_(true) {}
  ~scope_exit()
  {
    if (run_)
      f_(); // RAII semantics apply, expected not to throw
  }

  // "in place" construction expected, no default ctor provided either
  // also unclear what should be done with the old functor, should it
  // be called since it is no longer needed, or not since *this is not
  // going out of scope just yet...
  scope_exit& operator=(scope_exit&& rhs) = delete;
  // to be explicit...
  scope_exit(scope_exit const&) = delete;
  scope_exit& operator=(scope_exit const&) = delete;
};

template <typename F>
scope_exit<F> make_scope_exit(F&& f) noexcept
{
  return scope_exit<F>{ std::forward<F>(f) };
}
```

Notes on the implementation;

- `std::function<void()>` can be used to erase the type of the functor. `std::function<void()>` offers exception guarantees on the move constructors based on the exception specific of the held function. A sample of this implementation is found [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64d5b3a0422d6142)
- These exception specifications are consistent the C++ proposal and GSL implementations
- I've redacted most of the motivation for the `noexcept`, more substantial detail is found in the [C++ proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0052r1.pdf)
- The "usual" RAII semantics of the destructor, hence the "scope exit" function is applicable; it will not `throw`, this is also consistent with the C++11 specification on the default exception specification for a destructor. See [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor), [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/130117/3747990), [GotW#47](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/047.htm) and [HIC++](http://www.codingstandard.com/rule/15-2-1-do-not-throw-an-exception-from-a-destructor/)

Other implementations can be found;

- [The C++ proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4189.pdf) mentioned above and [its revision (as of this writing)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0052r1.pdf)
- [Boost.ScopeExit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html)
- [The Microsoft GSL implementation](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/gsl/gsl_util)

Comment: I'll add further notes and exception specifications as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: (Peter Sommerlad's paper that you're referring to has a new revision: [P0052r1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0052r1.pdf).)

Comment: @KerrekSB. I'm glad that proposal hasn't fallen by the way side.

Answer (score 4):

You could 'abuse' `shared_ptr` for this:

```
m_theVariableToChange = true;
std::shared_ptr<void> resetFalse(nullptr, [&](void*){ m_theVariableToChange = false; });
```

---

If there are concerns about using `void` as template parameter `T`, I found the following in the C++ standard:

20.8.2.2§2:

> ... The template parameter T of shared_ptr may be an incomplete type.

This indicates that `T` is only used as a pointer, therefore using `void` should be fine.

Comment: I did not downvote, but probably it's not guaranteed that the deleter will execute when the first constructor argument is null

Comment: Yes, that could be a reason, thanks @Viktor. However, I tested it, it seems to work. Another reason could be using `void` I guess. I'm not sure if this is legal.

Comment: Dear downvoter, if the reason was `std::nullptr`, it's corrected now. Silly mistake, sorry for that.

Comment: Thanks, now I learned a new reason why `using namespace std` is bad ;-)

Comment: @ViktorSehr. Given `~shared_ptr()` effects "If *this is empty or shares ownership with another shared_ptr instance (use_count() > 1),
there are no side effects." and "A shared_ptr object is empty if it does not own a pointer." §20.10.2.2, it should be ok for constructing it with a null pointer - it then owns a null pointer; but I think it is only just ok, I'm sure if it was originally intended to work this way (but it does seem to work).

Comment: @alain. It works - but must be used carefully. The semantics of the `shared_ptr` allow for shared ownership and if the `shared_ptr` is inadvertently copied, the "execute at scope exit" may not work as expected. The onus would be on the developer to make sure there are no copies made - the compiler would not be able to help in this regard. As an aside; a `unique_ptr` would not work here, since it's destructor requires a non-null pointer before it runs the "deleter".

Comment: Thanks for the info @Niall. A copy to another `shared_ptr` with the same scope would be ok though. (I guess that would be the most common case of inadvertently copying it.)

Comment: @M.M I don't follow. The answer initialises the `shared_ptr` with `nullptr`, not the address (not pointer) of any variable.

Comment: @Niall OK, I was imagining that the `unique_ptr` would point to the variable in question, and the custom deleter would set it to false instead of invoking `delete`. But that is a lame idea as it is unintuitive to a reader.

Comment: @Niall, it's no accident that it works, that's a feature of shared_ptr. The relevant constructor very clearly says it owns the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard version of this.

The [CppGoreGuidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md) Support Library ([GSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL)) has a generalized version of this called [finally](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl_util.h) but that library is not production quality yet. Its definitely recommended practice.

#### [E.19](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#e19-use-a-final_action-object-to-express-cleanup-if-no-suitable-resource-handle-is-available): Use a `final_action` object to express cleanup if no suitable resource handle is available

#### Reason

`finally` is less verbose and harder to get wrong than `try`/`catch`.

#### Example

```
void f(int n)
{
    void* p = malloc(1, n);
    auto _ = finally([p] { free(p); });
    // ...
}
```

#### Note

`finally` is not as messy as `try`/`catch`, but it is still ad-hoc.
Prefer proper resource management objects.

Answer (score 1):

Similar question: [The simplest and neatest c++11 ScopeGuard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28413370/1505939)

On that thread is described a similar guard for invoking an arbitrary function. To solve your problem, invoke a lambda that resets your variable.

For example, the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28413370/1505939) for your code would be:

```
scope_guard guard1 = [&]{ m_theVariableToChange = false; };
```

Another answer on that thread notes that a similar concept has been proposed for C++17 standardization; and there is also a C++03 solution presented.